# Could Regular thinset be used on Large format tiles

Tags: ceramic-tile, thinset

I have a full bag of regular thinset and want to use it for 1 foot by 2 feet tiles on floor. Could I use regular thinset or shall buy a bag of Large format tile thinset?

Is there huge difference in them? And if I use regular what could be the issue. My floor is pretty flat.

Answer (score 2):

The regular thinset (properly applied) will be fine on the tile side. Make the mix a bit stiffer to give more support to the heavier tile (don't mix it too thin). More of a concern would be on the subfloor side of things- be sure the thinset is compatible with what? A concrete subfloor ? A wood subfloor ? The labels on the bag would give a good indication of compatibility.